# I can't figure out how to populate dynamic reference in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, populate

This is my user model code. I am referencing the favorites using dynamic referencing as there are three types of posts that can be added to favorites

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    contact:{
      type:Number,
      required: true,
      unique:true
    },
    cnic: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    favorites: [
      {
        postType: {
          type: String
        },
        postId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          refPath: 'postType'
        },
      }
    ],
    itemsRented: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Rent',
      }
    ],
    itemsRentedOut: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Rent',
      }
    ],
    collectionRequestsSent: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'CommunityService',
      }
    ],
    itemsCollected: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'CommunityService',
      }
    ],
    servicesOrdered: [
      {
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Services'
      }
    ],
    paymentDetails: {
      card: { type: Number },
      cvc: { type: Number },
      name: { type: String },
      email: {type: String },
      expiryDate: {
        month: { type: Number },
        year: { type: Number }
      },
    },
    address: { type: String },
    isDisputeResolutionStaff: {
      type: String,
      default: false
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password)
}

userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified('password')) {
    next()
  }

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt)
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

export default User
```

This is my controller. I want to get the posts' details added to favorites by using populate but when I run the code it returns the user object not the post details

```js
const getFavorites = asyncHandler(async(req,res) => {
  await User.
  findById("61b51adfb7b8a64fd87420d3").
  populate("favorites").
  exec(function (err, story) {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    console.log(story);
  });
})
```

Comment: which table should favorites column refers to ?

Comment: It refers to either one of Services, Rent, CommunityService

Comment: You should specify ref=' Model name '.